# Maintain position in ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Tags: java, queue

I need to maintain a list of InetSocketAdress objects.  I have a ConcurrentLinkedQueue that contains these objects,  I do not want to remove objects from the queue but I need to know where I am in the queue.  I have a solution but for some reason I'm thinking there must be a better way.

```
private static final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<InetSocketAddress> allSocketAddrs 
        = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
public List<InetSocketAddress> activeSocketAddrs = new ArrayList();
private Integer queuePos = 0;

public void addInetSocketAddr(InetSocketAddress isa){
    if(!allSocketAddrs.contains(isa)){
        allSocketAddrs.add(isa);
    }
}
private void getNewInetSokcetAddrs(){
    Object[] newAddrs = allSocketAddrs.toArray();

    for(int x = queuePos;x<newAddrs.length;x++){
        InetSocketAddress isa = (InetSocketAddress)newAddrs[x];
        //items added to this list CAN/WILL be removed.
        activeSocketAddrs.add(isa);
        queuePos++;
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with all this?

Comment: I'm trying to maintain a unique list of InetSocketAddress objects.  I need a thread safe queue all threads can add to and the thread that processes the InetSocketAddress objects will have a list of InetSocketAdress it is using, ie ones that are active.  I don't want to remove objects from the queue to prevent processing duplicates.

Comment: Couldn't you use a separate queue for processing (where you *can* remove items from), and use a more efficient collection (a `Set`) for the `allSocketAddrs`?

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually want a queue. There are thread-safe implementations of `List` and `Set`, such as [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) and [`CopyOnWriteArraySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html).

Comment: @SeanVanGorder those are unnecessarily heavy if there are lots of inserts. `ConcurrentHashMap` would work nicely though.

Comment: I can change to a thread-safe list or a HashMap, but, doesn't my issue still exist of maintaining a list of all and a list of active?

Comment: I don't see it as a problem that you're maintaining 2 collections. But you don't have to do it so clumsily. Of course I have no idea what the big picture is, but the code in question is not very elegant and with large amounts of elements would be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'd separate the "all" collection and the new items as follows. It's a bit ugly to add an element to a different collection in `computeIfAbsent()`, but this way you can easily and efficiently get new items.

Example uses `LinkedBlockingQueue` because `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` doesn't have `drainTo`. The `getAllNew()` method also works differently (a bulk get of new elements), since you don't need to actively update the active list. If you want to handle the elements one by one, you could provide directt access to the queue.

```
private static final Map<InetSocketAddress, Object> allSocketAddrs = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private static final LinkedBlockingQueue<InetSocketAddress> activeSocketAddrs = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
private final static Object DUMMY = new Object();

public void addInetSocketAddr(InetSocketAddress isa){
    allSocketAddrs.computeIfAbsent(isa, key -> {
        activeSocketAddrs.add(key);
        return DUMMY;
    }
}

private List<InetSocketAddress> getAllNew() {
    List<InetSocketAddress> list = new ArrayList<>();
    activeSocketAddrs.drainTo(list);
    return list;
}
// Different threads could use this to get the queue and do a blocking
// take() for example
private Queue<InetSocketAddress> getNewQueue() {
    return activeSocketAddrs;
}
```